# POST form using ajax and then trigger colorbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I'm trying to post a form using jquery-ajax and at the same time load a hidden div on a colorbox pop-over.

The hidden div to load is called "#hidden-div" .

So far i have the code below:

Any ideas on how to make it post ALL the values and then trigger the colorbox pop-over with the hidden div?

The code below is not posting the data and not triggering the pop over :(

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmSS4").submit(function(event,dontCheck) {
        if(dontCheck === true) return;
        $.ajax({
        type     : 'POST',
        url      : "http://clientes.cupon0km.com/form.php?form=4",
        data     : $(this).serialize(),
        dataType : 'jsonp'
    });
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $("#hidden-div").colorbox({inline:true, width:"auto", fixed:true});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: To what `hidden div` are you referring? Also, is the form submit event being triggered in the `success` callback just being stopped by `if(dontCheck === true) return;` in the event handler for the `#dinero-form` form? If so, why?

Comment: sorry about the confusion, my bad, the dinero-form should not be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your ajax statement with this:

```
  $.ajax({
       type     : 'POST',
       url      : "http://clientes.cupon0km.com/form.php?form=4",
        data     : $(this).serialize(),
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success: function( data ) {
           $.colorbox({inline:true, width:"auto", fixed:true, href:"#hidden-div"});
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The script is a little obscure but if I understanded it right, you should try something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#frmSS4").submit(function(event,dontCheck) {
   if(dontCheck === true) return;
   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "http://clientes.cupon0km.com/form.php?form=4",
   data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data) {
               $("#dinero-form").trigger("submit",true); // What is this?
               $.colorbox({html: $('#hidden-div').html()});
       }
   });
   event.preventDefault(); 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry the #dinero-form line should not be there, tested your script but its not working, any idea?

Comment: What does exactly happens? Is the form submitted? Do you receive any console error?

Comment: please check out the original post i updated the code but i cant get it work nor trigger the pop over

Answer (score 0):

To send form data you can use `.serialize()` which serializes all the data in your form, instead of doing it one input at a time:

```
   data: { email: $('#email').val(), CustomFields_17_4: $('#CustomFields_17_4').val(),     CustomFields_12_4: $('#CustomFields_12_4').val(), CustomFields_13_4:     $('#CustomFields_13_4').val(), CustomFields_16_4: $('#CustomFields_16_4').val() },
```

Can change to:

```
   data: $(this).serialize(),
```

With `this` referring to the form (because this code is within the event handler for the form).

To open a colorbox instance you just need to call the initialization code inside the `success` callback function.

Docs for `.serialize()`: http://api.jquery.com/serialize

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmSS4").submit(function(event,dontCheck) {
        if(dontCheck === true) return;
        $.ajax({
            type     : 'POST',
            url      : "http://clientes.cupon0km.com/form.php?form=4",
            data     : $(this).serialize(),
            dataType : 'jsonp'//this line will allow you to do cross-domain AJAX requests (I believe this is one of your problems)
        });
        event.preventDefault(); 
        //initialize colorbox here, Antonio Languna has an example in his answer
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: excellent! but how would you also trigger the #hidden-div with colorbox at the same time its submiting the post?

Comment: In your `success` callback function just add the code to initialize the colorbox plugin. Right before or after the `$("#dinero-form").trigger("submit",true)` line.

Comment: sorry the #dinero-form line shoujld not be there, how can i trigger the popup at the same time they you hit submit?

Comment: Oh well that's even easier, you don't need the `success` callback function, just place the colorbox code inside the `submit` event handler for the form (after the first line that returns if needed). I updated my answer.

Comment: syntax error on line event.preventDefault(); but still cant trigger colorbox using antonio's suggestion, also tried this

$("#hidden-div").colorbox({inline:true, width:"auto", fixed:true});

Comment: @sebas If you copied the code strait from my answer I accidently added an extra `}` (bracket) directly after the `$.ajax()` code (which may very well be the error you're getting). My code has been updated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6675/discussion-between-sebas-and-jasper)

Answer (score 0):

User html instead of href as bellow

> $(#divid).colorbox({inline:true, width:"auto",
>   fixed:true,html:data});